# Redirect old subsite url to new subsite url using URL redirect generic IIS Rewrite Rule

Tags: sitecore-api, multilingual, iis, url-rewrite

in existing production we have URL structure as follows
https://mainsite.com/subsite

Now the sub site URL structure changed as follows
https://mainsite.com/newsubsite/subsite2

We want to redirect old sub site landing page and all the inner pages to redirect to new url structure
I.e., when user browse
https://mainsite.com/subsite it should redirect to https://mainsite.com/newsubsite/subsite2

And when user browse https://mainsite.com/subsite/innerpage it should redirect to  https://mainsite.com/newsubsite/subsite2/innerpage

The inner page name don't have any name changes. Just need to replace "subsite" with "newsubsite/subsite2"

**Edit:** one more scenario need to handle. Some times language code e.g.: "en" will come in the URL as like below
https://mainsite.com/en/subsite

In this case it need to redirect to https://mainsite.com/en/newsubsite/subsite2

Same for inner pages as well

Any body help me to create a generic rewrite rule to do this job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple rule like that will do the trick:

```
<rule name="subsite rule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^([a-z]{2}(\-[a-z]{2})?/)?subsite(/.*){0,1}$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}newsubsite/subsite2{R:3}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Remember to recycle app pool after you edit your config - simple site restart related to config change is not enough usually.

`Match` is for the urls starting (optionally with language code either 2 letters like `en` or 4 letters with hyphen like `en-us`), and then with `subsite` and then either nothing after it or urls starting with `subsite/`, e.g.

```
https://mainsite.com/subsite
https://mainsite.com/subsite/
https://mainsite.com/subsite/subfolder
https://mainsite.com/subsite/sub/sub/sub
https://mainsite.com/en/subsite
https://mainsite.com/en-us/subsite/
https://mainsite.com/en-es/subsite/subfolder
https://mainsite.com/en/subsite/sub/sub/sub
```

Whatever comes after `subsite` will be added to resulting url after `/newsubsite/subsite2`.

`appendQueryString="true"` makes sure that if there is query string, it will be included in the new url as well.

Comment: this is perfectly working fine. but I found one more scenario and added to the question. your help is very much appreciated

Comment: answer updated.

Comment: Thanks. it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect your existing production we have URL to sub site URL as below

```
<rule name="ms1" stopProcessing="true"> 
<match url="^subsite/?$" /> 
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny"> <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" 
pattern="^(mainsite.com|www.mainsite.com)$" /> </conditions> 
<action type="Redirect" url="https://mainsite.com/newsubsite/subsite2" /> </rule>
```

I tested this with my instance URL and it is working as expected.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this will not append inner page urls

Comment: have you tried this, is it not appending inner page urls?

Comment: Hi @Rishiraj, thanks you for you help. Marek answer is working for me. so I have used that.